# How to determine the python is mingw or official build?

Tags: python, windows, gcc, mingw, msys2

I am using python in the MSYS2 environment. The MSYS2 has its own built MINGW python version. Also I can install the official python from the www.python.org.

Here is the problem: If I want to write a python code need to know the python version is MINGW or the official one, how can I do it?

Here are some ways I can image.

1. Use the "sys.prefix" object. It tells the installation directory. the MSYS2 usually installed in the directory X:\msys2\.... and the official one install in the X:\Python27\ as default. But users may change the installation directory. So this is not a good way.
2. Use the "sys.version" object can get the version strings show with the compiler name. It shows the MINGW python compiled by GCC, the official one compiled by MSC. But there may have some possibility that there is an other version's python also built by GCC or MSC.

Is there any more elegant way can do this?

Comment: As far as I know, the two ways you listed are the two reasonable ways to get to know the python version. But I'm curious, how would it matter to you which version the user has? They both will provide identical user experience for the same build number.

Comment: By the way, you can check the environment variable MSYSTEM: if it exists, it usually means you are running inside an MSYS2 shell.  But I don't know if you care about supporting users who run the official Python interpreter from an MSYS2 shell.

Comment: Hi @marcus, the cffi didn't support MINGW version. I would like to see if there is a more robust way to let the program detect it then use other functions.

Comment: @DavidGrayson : I do need to run it from the MSYS2

Comment: I would suggest you to actually check if cffi is supported. Check if the import works using a `try...except` clause, and raise a suitable error.

Answer (score 6):

Mingw python3 build patched official `sysconfig.get_platform()` function so it returns "mingw" and can be used for distinguishing from official python builds.

https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/blob/abd06ca92d876b9db05dd65f27d71c4ebe2673a9/mingw-w64-python2/0410-MINGW-build-extensions-with-GCC.patch#L54

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to check if GCC is in sys.version.

For example:

```
import sys
MSYS2 = ("GCC" in sys.version)
print(MSYS2)
> True
```

This works because the sys.version information has the type of compiler used, and MinGW uses GCC.

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.version)"
3.7.4 (default, Aug 15 2019, 18:17:27)  [GCC 9.2.0 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Comment: Some versions of MSYS2 come with CLANG instead of GCC. So this might not be robust any more. I haven't tested though.

Answer (score -3):

`sys.platform` gives `msys` when in msys-Python.

Comment: MinGW Python is not MSYS-Python. On MSYS2, one is in `/usr` and one is in `/mingw{32,64}`.